# failed to insert combobox in datagrid in dojotoolkit

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!'],
    function(lang, DataGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, dom){
    var data = {
      identifier: "id",
      items: []
    };
    var data_list = [
      { col1: "normal", col2: 'X', col3: 'A', col4: 29.91,col5:1,combo:'combo'},
      { col1: "important", col2: 'Y', col3: 'B', col4: 9.33,col5:2,combo:'combo'},
      { col1: "important", col2: 'Z', col3: 'C', col4: 19.34,col5:1,combo:'combo'}

```
];
var rows = 10;
for(var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++){
    data.items.push(lang.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
}
var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
var layout = [[
  {'name': 'SNO', 'field': 'id', 'width': '100px'},
  {'name': 'Name', 'field': 'col2', 'width': '100px'},
  {'name': 'Batch ', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '200px'},
  {'name': 'Percent', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '150px'},
  {'name': 'stage', 'field': 'col5', 'width': '150px'}
  {'name':'combo','field':'combo','width':'200px',
      'require':'js.dojox.grid.cell.dijit.js','cellType':'js.dojox.grid.cells.ComboBox','options':[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],'editable':'true'}
]];
var grid = new DataGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    store: store,
    structure: layout,
    rowSelector: '20px'});
    grid.placeAt("gridDiv");
    grid.startup();
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

```
dojox/grid/cells/dijit
```

to your require

Comment: added but no response @tik27

Comment: Take a look at my fiddle,its working there, see if there are any differences::http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/g3JqJ/

Comment: tanq @tik27 i corrected my mistake got the answer......how to show th saved data in dropdown when i click on combo column cell

Comment: how to show combo box directly without double click.....what can i place here combo:' '

Comment: Its a grid option::   var grid = new DataGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        singleClickEdit:true
    });